# Is it possible to provide implementation of Go interface from Python?

Tags: python, api, plugins, go

I have a Go lib which does concurrent processing on variable data, I have a (simplified) interface:

```
type Handler interface {
    Accepts(id []byte) bool
    ProcessUnit(u []byte) []byte
}
```

Currently, library end-developer (user) might write go code which implements this interface and a library can work on end-developer data structures.

Now the real question: (lets skip overhead), is it possible to provide implementation of that interface written in another language (with Python in mind)? My intention is to provide a "Plugin API" so anyone can add handlers, written in eg: Python (or possibly other languages)

I already have a working implementation which uses zeromq to pass data around go<->python, but this feels "non-natural". The utopia I want to achieve is that an lib user places `plugins.py` file in predefined location, and go can load plugins automatically on startup, is it possible or I'm looking in wrong direction?

Comment: Message passing using zeromq is a perfectly fine way to implement inter process communication, if that is what you need.  Can you elaborate on what your utopia is and why you want to achieve it to help us understand it?

Comment: I wan't to avoid boilerplate code/steps to separated start and stop of a producers(python plugins) and consumer(go lib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go has no dynamic loading of modules (at least in zero and first order approximation), so no, you cannot just place a plugins.py somewhere and have a Go programm load and use it, at least not from Go itself...

...But you might be able to use go-python https://github.com/sbinet/go-python or goPy https://github.com/qur/gopy which should allow you to run the python interpreter from Go and the python interpreter *can* do dynamic module loads. This will get a bit ugly with some forth and back between Go and Python but should be doable.

Passing data around (either zeromq or maybe direct via package net/rpc) doesn't seem "non-natural" to me...

(Sidenote: If somebody can write proper Python code and gets some help understanding pointers he should be able to write Go code in a few days.)